# Code Commenting - Should design pattern used be commented

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, comments

If a design pattern has been used in a class, should the comments at the top of the class or at the top of a relevant method explain the specific design pattern used or the actual functionality.

i.e.

```
/**
 *  Class MyClass
 *
 * Utilizes Factory Method patter to accomplish xyz
 */
```

or

```
/**
 *  Class MyClass
 *
 *  Allows the creation of objects for xyz
 */
```

This is extremely simplified to illustrate

The main part of my query is whether to rely on other people wondering what design patterns were used, or if it may come across like being a smart arse by just saying what design pattern was used

Comment: My rule of thumb is that where good naming and encapsulation ends, good commenting begins.  In any case, what possible harm is there in letting someone know what pattern is being used, so long as the comment is maintained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common practice is to name your classes (ie XyzFactory) so it's easy to see what pattern you use and give the actual funcionality in the comment, preferably more descriptive than only describing what the design pattern already does.

Comment: You have a couple of upvotes for this, but I wouldnt have thought this would be good practice having classes around the codebase with a suffix of the pattern being used i.e. XyzFactory XyzSingleton XyzTemplate - im not sure though so i will take it on board.  Is this common in many frameworks?

Comment: Yes this is a common practice in modern frameworks, such as Symfony2 and Zend Framework 2. Older or just plain worse frameworks might not use it as much.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an external dependancy then I would think mentioning it is good. If it is contrasting to another function (cf. PHP's [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/mt-rand) vs. [`rand`](http://php.net/rand)) then it is also good to mention.

Otherwise, it's unnecessary but still up to personal preference whether to mention it or not.